# Debug error in Visual Studio:'Error occurred creating the form.No process is associated with this object.'

Tags: .net, forms, debugging, exception, process

Another enfuriating random error in Visual Studio. Everything working fine and now when I try to launch a debug via the usual means (F5), I get this error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: No process is associated with this object.'
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at C64DebuggerGUI.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance)
   at C64DebuggerGUI.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_cdbf()
   at C64DebuggerGUI.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at C64DebuggerGUI.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args)
```

And the point in code where the exception is caught:

**Application.Designer.vb**

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Namespace My

Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
        Me.IsSingleInstance = false
        Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
        Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
        Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
    End Sub

    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.C64DebuggerGUI.cdbf  ' < !!!!!!EXCEPTION HERE!!!!!!
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Google hasn't been my friend on this occasion. The class/form C64DebuggerGUI.cdbf  definitely exists.

I did change the startup form which owrked once, i.e. it booted to this sub form in the debugger. However, changed it back to cdbf.vb and then tried the sub form again, getting the same error elsewhere in my code. I.e:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: No process is associated with this object.'
```

in:

```
 Private Sub Initialise()
    Db = cdbf.MainDb
    ToolsBindingSource.DataSource = Db.Tables("Tools") ' <-- !!! EXCEPTION HERE !!!
    ' truncated as code above just illustrative
```

I'm not sure if it's my code or a quirk of VS, but it's hellish frustrating. It's brought me to full stop with no way to fix :(

How can I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. Solved it. The culprit was this code in cdbf.vb:

```
Private Sub RefreshC64DebugWnd()

    If My.Settings.SuppressC64dAtStartup Then Return
    ShowWindow(C64Dproc.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE)
    wait(100)
    ShowWindow(C64Dproc.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE)

End Sub

Private Sub MainSplitContainer_SplitterMoved(sender As Object, e As SplitterEventArgs) Handles MainSplitContainer.SplitterMoved

    RefreshC64DebugWnd()

End Sub
```

I guess the splitter.moved event was getting fired prior to the instantiation of C64Dproc (process). Hence the 'process not found' error. I guess because this was being manipulated via 'unmanaged' (?) code, VS wasn't able to point me to the culprit?

Of course, the true irony is, it was the last 3 lines of my class!